# mat-table not remembering select all checkbox state on each row during pagination

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I use [Material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) `mat-table` with checkbox option on each row as shown on this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssv6fc-k34hn6?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.html).

- Is it possible to pass the selection status of the master (select all
  / none) checkbox between pages by using a `Map`, etc?

On the other hand, I am not sure if the behavior on the demo is normal, because it seems to be just updating the rows rather than columns.

Any ideas about these 2 items?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `datasource` is being set with a slice of the `array` according to the current page.

- You will need to iterate over the `array` to set the select all state
  for the rows, which is then sliced back into the `datasource` to render the view.

in the `masterToggle(ref)` function change this:

```
 this.dataSource.forEach(row => {
    this.selection.select(row);
    console.log(row);
  });
```

to this:

```
this.array.forEach(row => {
        this.selection.select(row);
        console.log(row);
      });
```

**Additional Thoughts:**

> Regarding if this is normal behavior or not, this is custom business
> logic that was written in the demo.
>
> - It is not behavior in the material library or part of the library spec
>
> Because I do not know the requirements/scope for this demo, it may be in fact correct behavior
> according to the authors spec... but this does not mean your
> requirements are incorrect.

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssv6fc-z4fpyv?file=app/table-selection-example.ts

Comment: Thanks for help, voted up. On the other hand, could you give me an example regarding to the array parameter? Maybe updating some [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kbmuh-szd399?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts).

Comment: See revised answer to include stackblitz

Comment: You rock!.. Voted up ;) I am wondering 2 points that is so crucial for me:

Comment: **1.** What changes should be made if we want the "Select All" only select/deselect current page rather than whole pages?

Comment: **2.** Unfortunately there is no id column in my model and it has just `name` and `age` fields (I know it is weird but it is related to something). So, I am wondering if I create a base data model or interface in order to use our models in table properly by getting benefit from its `position` or `id` fields that our model does not have (probably mo position column of course).

Comment: How can I perform this, could you please post an update to your answer?

Comment: Your original question has been resolved/answered and it should be marked as such. If you have additional items you would like assistance with, that go beyond the scope of the original question you posted here, please create a new SO question providing examples of your data model (that was not part of this original question) preferably in a stackblitz and I or someone will review and assist with your additional questions.

Comment: Of course I will mark it as answer, but the last 2 points are also related to this question and by answering this I think you are easily help me about these 2 points. It is too difficult to find an experienced user in SO regarding to Angular Material. So, I would be appreciated if you help also about that (I have already voted++ and will of course mark it as answer ;)

Comment: You clearly misunderstand the nature of SO. Attempting to use a bread crumb trail of upvotes to entice users to entertain your scope creep approach to questions is likely the reason you are struggling to find quality answers. This question has been resolved. Because your new questions go beyond the scope of the original question, as one of them is about a data model that does not apply to the DEMO stackblitz you asked about, I will not be assisting you further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224198/discussion-between-jack-and-marshal).

Comment: Ok, I can create a new question for my last 2 comments. Would you help on that question?